# XPages tracelog - output of JavaScript print() statement is not logged or shown

Tags: logging, printing, xpages

In the ...**/IBM/Lotus/Notes/Data/workspace/logs** directory I have seen some tracelog files written in XML, but I can't see the output of JavaScript print() statements in any of them.

I have already tried the XPagesLogFileReader Application from openntf.org: there are no tracelog files found at all. Console log files are shown.

How and where can I get and see current tracelog file entries? At the moment,I`m testing the examples of "Mastering XPages" Book.. there are lots of JavaScript print() statements.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on a domino server the console output is saved to:

C:\ **Domino Dir** \data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT\  and then the latest "console.log" file.

However the easiest way by far is to simply leave the server console open and just view that as it is printing.

if you are using the local web preview server heres a link to take a look at:

http://www.juliusbuss.de/web/youatnotes/blog-jb.nsf/dx/see-ssjs-print-statements-in-local-web-preview.htm

Comment: The link changed [http://julianbuss.net/see-ssjs-print-statements-in-local-web-preview-htm/](http://julianbuss.net/see-ssjs-print-statements-in-local-web-preview-htm/)